# How to put values inside multiple column families in hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am looking for a hbase put command that can insert values into multiple column families for a same rowkey in hbase table

Let's say I have a hbase table named **'emp'** with two column families such as **'personal'** and **'educational'**

I am applying the below command . It throws some syntax error

```
put 'emp' ,'100', 'personal:name', 'SURENDER', 'educational:degree', 'BTECH'

ERROR: no method 'add' for arguments (org.jruby.java.proxies.ArrayJavaProxy,org.jruby.java.proxies.ArrayJavaProxy,org.jruby.RubyString,org.jruby.java.proxies.ArrayJavaProxy) on Java::OrgApacheHadoopHbaseClient::Put
```

However if try  separate put commands for each column family then it works

```
put 'emp', '100' ,'personal:name', 'SURENDER'
put 'emp', '100', 'educational:degree', 'BTECH'
```

Could anybody tell me what went wrong  when I try to apply put command for 2 column families?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. Put can only be applied to insert a single value.