# creating base table with multiple column families

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am new to hbase. I am using HBase version 1.1.2 on Microsoft Azure. I have data that looks like this

```
id  num1  rating
 1   254      2
 2    40      3
 3    83      1
 4   120      1
 5    91      5
 6   101      2
 7    17      1
 8    10      2
 9    11      3
10    31      1
```

I tried to create a table with two colum families of the form

```
create 'table1', 'family1', 'family2'
```

when I loaded my table

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv \
-Dimporttsv.columns="HBASE_ROW_KEY,family1:num1, family2:rating" table1 /metric.csv
```

I got the error

```
Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedWithDetailsException: Failed 5560 actions: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.NoSuchColumnFamilyException: Column family family2 does not exist in region table1
```

when I modified my table with one column family it worked

```
create 'table1', 'family1'



hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv \
-Dimporttsv.columns="HBASE_ROW_KEY,family1:num1, family1:rating" table1 /metric.csv
```

How do I adjust my table creation to account for multiple column families?

Comment: What is the version of HBase you are using?

Comment: I'm using version 1.1.2 on Microsoft Azure

Comment: The error suggests that the table does not actually have the two column families. Can you do a "describe 'table1'" to check. If you see only one column family, try using
create 'table1', {NAME =>'family1'} , {NAME => 'family2'}

Answer (score 0):

HBase ImportTsv internally uses PUT operations to load the data into HBase tables.

PUT only supports loading into single column family at a time 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36302240/how-to-put-values-inside-multiple-column-families-in-hbase) [Here](http://grokbase.com/t/sqoop/user/122p9zbh7f/importing-more-than-one-column-family-in-hbase-through-sqoop) and from [Documentation](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/ops_mgt.html#importtsv)

Comment: ImportTsv allows loading to multiple column families and Put operation also supports  multiple column families since ancient days. The first link you provided talks about doing Put from hbase shell, and the other link is because of non-existence of atomicity guarantees across multiple column families , also in an ancient version of HBase.

Comment: Can you please give an example or point me to the documentation

Comment: See https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#importtsv for ImportTSV documentation.
Also see https://hbase.apache.org/1.1/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put.html#add(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.Cell) for the version of Put used by ImportTSV.   
Here is another version of Put that directly supports adding multiple column families as long as it's the same row: https://hbase.apache.org/1.1/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put.html#addColumn(byte[],%20byte[],%20byte[])